# iframe for Angular application not working, but only on mobile devices

Tags: ios, angularjs, django, iframe

I have an AngularJS application with a Django backend. I inserted an iframe onto another site and the application is working fine on desktop, and also on the Chrome debugger mobile menu. It also works on mobile devices when going to the website. Its ONLY when I go to a site that has an iframe to my Angular app on a mobile device where it doesn't work. It loads the html, but none of the data retrieved from our backend is populating the page in the iframe. Completely at a loss. I know its not my code since it works on all the other versions. Could this be an iframe issue, or perhaps an iOS issue ?

**Update**

It also works on my Samsung tablet, so it seems like its only an iOS issue

**Iframe**

```
<iframe src="http://66.175.220.49/dealer-swipe/#/3087" scrolling="auto" align="center" frameBorder="0" height="500px" width="100%" class="myIframe"></iframe>
```

**UPDATE 2**
I checked the logs on my server, and noticed that sometimes when Angular makes AJAX calls there is some OSWrite error.

```
ERROR 2018-02-09 21:52:21,955 ajax_views.py dealer_info 10 GETTING THE DEALER ...
ERROR 2018-02-09 21:52:21,959 ajax_views.py dealer_info 28 DEALER 3087 SUCCESS
[pid: 11719|app: 0|req: 34/34] 107.77.169.5 () {48 vars in 917 bytes} [Fri Feb  9 21:52:21 2018] POST /dealer/3087 => generated 402 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
ERROR 2018-02-09 21:52:22,103 ajax_views.py get_filters 13 GETTING FILTERS
ERROR 2018-02-09 21:52:24,394 ajax_views.py get_filters 113 GET FILTERS SUCCESS
Fri Feb  9 21:52:24 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /dswipe/filters/ (ip 107.77.169.5) !!!
Fri Feb  9 21:52:24 2018 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 216]
OSError: write error
[pid: 11719|app: 0|req: 35/35] 107.77.169.5 () {50 vars in 1008 bytes} [Fri Feb  9 21:52:22 2018] POST /dswipe/filters/ => generated 0 bytes in 2293 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Fri Feb  9 21:52:24 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /dealer-swipe/ (ip 107.77.169.5) !!!
Fri Feb  9 21:52:24 2018 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 216]
OSError: write error
[pid: 11719|app: 0|req: 36/36] 107.77.169.5 () {42 vars in 822 bytes} [Fri Feb  9 21:52:24 2018] GET /dealer-swipe/ => generated 0 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 4 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
ERROR 2018-02-09 21:52:24,400 ajax_views.py next_vehicle 403 PREPARING TO GET NEXT VEHICLE ...
3087
Tracy Langston Ford - Lincoln - Mercury, LLC
ERROR 2018-02-09 21:52:24,427 ajax_views.py next_vehicle 485 GETTING NEXT VEHICLE SUCCESS !
Fri Feb  9 21:52:24 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /account/next_vehicle/ (ip 107.77.169.5) !!!
Fri Feb  9 21:52:24 2018 - uwsgi_response_write_headers_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 216]
OSError: write error
```

Comment: what is the url like for the iframe?

Comment: <iframe src="http://66.175.220.49/dealer-swipe/#/3087" scrolling="auto" align="center" frameBorder="0" height="500px" width="100%" class="myIframe"></iframe>

Comment: Iframes do not work in ios application.

Comment: Theres no need to keep referring to it as an "actual" mobile device and an "actual" Angular app. I'm very confused by your description of the problem, are you writing an iOS application using hybrid or webviews that won't load the iframe? Or are you saying that visiting your site in safari on the iPhone is not working. Also, just guessing here, but there could be issues with it being a `http` URL instead of `https`. I know that when writing iOS apps, there are restrictions put in place to stop unencrypted http calls.

Comment: Have you tried passing the URL from the controller using $sce?

Comment: @Simon, sorry I meant just visiting the site in safari on an iphone. I was running on limited brain juice last night trying to figure this out, and my SO posting was frantic :P

Comment: @Jonathon I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try avoiding binding the url directly to iframe, You can try putting this in your controller. **`trustAsResourceUrl`** is the method you need to use

**HTML**

**`<iframe   ng-src="{{trustSrc(object.url)}}"></iframe>`**

and in

**controller**

```
 $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
       return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
```